# Confidence Intervals for Lethal Dose (LD) for Logistic Regression in R

Tags: r, glm, logistic-regression

I want to find Lethal Dose (`LD50`) with its confidence interval in `R`. Other softwares line Minitab, SPSS, SAS provide three different versions of such confidence intervals. I could not find such intervals in any package in `R` (I also used `findFn` function from `sos` package).

How can I find such intervals? I coded for one type of intervals based on Delta method (as not sure about it correctness) but would like to use any established function from `R` package. Thanks

**MWE:**

```
dose <- c(10.2, 7.7, 5.1, 3.8, 2.6, 0)
total <- c(50, 49, 46, 48, 50, 49) 
affected <- c(44, 42, 24, 16, 6, 0)
finney71 <- data.frame(dose, total, affected)


fm1 <- glm(cbind(affected, total-affected) ~ log(dose),
 family=binomial(link = logit), data=finney71[finney71$dose != 0, ])
summary(fm1)$coef

             Estimate Std. Error   z value     Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -4.886912  0.6429272 -7.601035 2.937717e-14
log(dose)    3.103545  0.3877178  8.004650 1.198070e-15


library(MASS)
xp <- dose.p(fm1, p=c(0.50, 0.90, 0.95))  # from MASS
xp.ci <- xp + attr(xp, "SE") %*% matrix(qnorm(1 - 0.05/2)*c(-1,1), nrow=1)
zp.est <- exp(cbind(xp, attr(xp, "SE"), xp.ci[,1], xp.ci[,2]))
dimnames(zp.est)[[2]] <- c("LD", "SE", "LCL","UCL")
zp.est  

                 LD       SE      LCL       UCL
p = 0.50:  4.828918 1.053044 4.363708  5.343724
p = 0.90:  9.802082 1.104050 8.073495 11.900771
p = 0.95: 12.470382 1.133880 9.748334 15.952512
```

Comment: I could not find many R packages on LD50, but from a brief literature search I believe you are applying the calculation correctly. Can you provide any information on the other methods used by Minitab, SPSS, and SAS such as the name of the statistical test used? What values do you get when you run the other programs for the CI?

Comment: Looks to me that you've done everything to find such functions in R if they existed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the package [drc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/drc/index.html), you can get the *ED50* (same calculation), along with confidence intervals.

```
library(drc) # Directly borrowed from the drc manual

mod <- drm(affected/total ~ dose, weights = total,
data = finney71[finney71$dose != 0, ], fct = LL2.2(), type = "binomial")

#intervals on log scale
ED(mod, c(50, 90, 95), interval = "fls", reference = "control") 

Estimated effective doses
(Back-transformed from log scale-based confidence interval(s))

     Estimate   Lower   Upper
1:50   4.8289  4.3637  5.3437
1:90   9.8021  8.0735 11.9008
1:95  12.4704  9.7483 15.9525
```

Which matches the manual output.

The "finney71" data is included in this package, and your calculation of confidence intervals **exactly** matches the example given by the `drc` folks, down to the "# from MASS" comment. You should give credit to them, rather than claiming you wrote the code.

---

There's a few other ways to figure this out. One is using parametric bootstrap, which is conveniently available through the `boot` package.

First, we'll refit the model.

```
library(boot)

finney71 <- finney71[finney71$dose != 0,] # pre-clean data 
fm1 <- glm(cbind(affected, total-affected) ~ log(dose),
                 family=binomial(link = logit), 
                 data=finney71)
```

And for illustration, we can figure out the LD50 and LD75.

```
statfun <- function(dat, ind) {
    mod <- update(fm1, data = dat[ind,])
    coefs <- coef(mod)
    c(exp(-coefs[1]/coefs[2]),
      exp((log(0.75/0.25) - coefs[2])/coefs[1]))
}

boot_out <- boot(data = finney71, statistic = statfun, R = 1000)
```

The `boot.ci` function can work out a variety of confidence intervals for us, using this object.

```
boot.ci(boot_out, index = 1, type = c('basic', 'perc', 'norm'))
##BOOTSTRAP CONFIDENCE INTERVAL CALCULATIONS
##Based on 999 bootstrap replicates
##
##CALL : 
##boot.ci(boot.out = boot_out, type = c("basic", "perc", "norm"), 
##    index = 1)

##Intervals : 
##Level      Normal              Basic              Percentile     
##95%   ( 3.976,  5.764 )   ( 4.593,  5.051 )   ( 4.607,  5.065 )
```

[image]

The confidence intervals using the normal approximation are thrown off quite a bit by a few extreme values, which the basic and percentile-based intervals are more robust to.

One interesting thing to note: if the sign of the slope is sufficiently unclear, we can get some rather extreme values (simulated as in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46523/how-to-simulate-artificial-data-for-logistic-regression), and discussed more thoroughly in [this blog post](http://andrewgelman.com/2011/06/21/inference_for_a/) by Andrew Gelman).

```
set.seed(1)
x <- rnorm(100)        
z = 0.05 + 0.1*x*rnorm(100, 0, 0.05) # small slope and more noise
pr = 1/(1+exp(-z))        
y = rbinom(1000, 1, pr)   
sim_dat <- data.frame(x, y)  
sim_mod <- glm(y ~ x, data = sim_dat, family = 'binomial')

statfun <- function(dat, ind) {
    mod <- update(sim_mod, data = dat[ind,])
    -coef(mod)[1]/coef(mod)[2]
}
sim_boot <- boot(data = sim_dat, statistic = statfun, R = 1000)
hist(sim_boot$t[,1], breaks = 100, 
          main = "Bootstrap of simulated model")
```

[image]

The delta method above gives us mean = 6.448, lower ci = -36.22, and upper ci = 49.12, and all of the bootstrap CIs give us similarly extreme estimates.

```
##Level      Normal              Basic              Percentile     
##95%   (-232.19,  247.76 )   ( -20.17,   45.13 )   ( -32.23,   33.06 )
```

Comment: +1 From what I can tell the CI for LD50 is exactly the normal interpretation ([example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Practical_example)). Not sure why a package would be needed.