# How to find LC50 using r?

Tags: r

I have run cadmium exposure (46h) test and now I want to find LC50 value(Lethal Concentration)and 95% confidence limits (upper and lower limits) using R ?

Here are my data:

```
Conc. mg/L  Dead    Live
C1  0   10
C2  0   10
C3  0   10
2   0   10
2   0   10
2   0   10
4   0   10
4   0   10
4   0   10
8   0   10
8   0   10
8   0   10
16  1   9
16  1   9
16  8   8
32  1   9
32  2   8
32  4   6
64  8   2
64  2   8
64  5   5
128 10  0
128 8   2
128 10  0
256 10  0
256 10  0
256 10  0
```

Comment: You might start by explaining what LC50 is.

Comment: OP I searched LC50 in r and many references showed up. How many have you read through before coming here?

Comment: we should reopen this so we can close it as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28053542/confidence-intervals-for-lethal-dose-ld-for-logistic-regression-in-r ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://www.ccohs.ca/oshanswers/chemicals/ld50.html), it seems that LC50 is the minimum concentration at which 50% or more of organisms die. You could aggregate your data to compute the proportion of organisms that died at each concentration level:

```
# Numeric concentration
dat$Conc.mg.L <- as.character(dat$Conc.mg.L)
dat$Conc.mg.L[dat$Conc.mg.L %in% c("C1", "C2", "C3")] <- 0
dat$Conc.mg.L <- as.numeric(dat$Conc.mg.L)

# Determine LC50
(agg <- tapply(dat$Dead / (dat$Dead+dat$Live), dat$Conc.mg.L, mean))
#         0         2         4         8        16        32        64       128       256 
# 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.2333333 0.2333333 0.5000000 0.9333333 1.0000000 
as.numeric(names(agg)[min(which(agg >= 0.5))])
# [1] 64
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer, however, I would  appreciate if you  could explain how to find  95% confidence limit for the LC50? (I tried to find references, but still i couldn't find any )

Comment: @NuwanSilva If you have an additional question I would encourage you to ask it using the "Ask Question" button. Please be sure to describe all the research you've done when you ask.